Highcharts colorAxix custom
Hi i have coloraxis like this
 stops:[
    [
        0,
        "#006622"
    ],
    [
        0.222,
        "#7bd020"
    ],
    [
        0.444,
        "#ffe500"
    ],
    [
        0.667,
        "#f79104"
    ],
    [
        1,
        "#ccc"
    ]
]


and i have minvalue in dataset 5 and maxvalue of dataset 8
but for value greater than 7 whose calculated positions are greater than 0.667 and whose color should be closer to  '#ccc', is falling in the color '#7bd020' some of the values greater than 7 are falling in the color '#f79104' also which is strange
Because in my defined stopsarray the values greater than 7 should fall closer to '#ccc'.
Please Help.
here's the jsfiddle link

Can you please share full code of highchart options?

hi, thanks for responding, i have attached jsfiddle link please check

add min: 5, max: 8 in colorAxis, and check.

Check in https://jsfiddle.net/xmd835tj/4/

Adding min and max extremes to the colorAxis seems to do the job, great!
